# how to get stream length or caret position in php?

Tags: php, stream

That is count all data in a stream without bringing it all to a string. Or maybe doing it two step, that is bring caret to end and then get position ?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php - I cant find any reference to caret position or size or length.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`fstat`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php) to the rescue!

*30 characters limit is non-sense*

Comment: It may be non-sense but it is part of the community rules. Instead of trying to get around it with non-sense, you should consider adding an example, link, and or description of *why* this answer is correct so it may help future visitors better.

Comment: What the indexes in return mean - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php#refsect1-function.stat-returnvalues